# Calling stored procedure through zapier but no inserted row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, zapier

We have mysql database on our Mariadb server, using myphpadmin to manage it, and using Zapier to manage the dataflow.

As a test, I created a simple stored procedure in the database that inserts a new row and returns the row with some values to a table with a PK (auto increment).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`massageo`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_customertest`(IN 
`INName` VARCHAR(255), IN `INPhone` VARCHAR(255), IN `INEmail` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

insert into customer (Name,Phone,Email)
values(INName,INPhone,INEmail);
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Name = INName;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call the procedure from myphpadmin server side, it works as it should, inserting a new row with the new values including a PK auto increment.

Now, Zapier has an integration called "MySQL", which has a action called "Find Row Via Custom Query". When I connect as root user and call the stored action

```
call massageo_MYSQL_TEST4.add_customertest('INName','INEmail','INPhone')
```

I don't get an error in Zapier. It throws back the new row together with a new customerId (auto increment) as if the row has been created. But when I look in phpmyadmin, the row has not been created.

Zapier says that they cannot see why no row has been inserted, only that the call of the stored procedure was a success. I also tried a similar service to Zapier, integromat, that has an integration called "call stored procedure". Here it also works perfect. I whitelisted Zapier's IP as a remote host, so now I don't know what to do.

I have spent a lot of time trying to find the answer with no luck. I found this:
[1](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cant-access-mysql-procedures-insufficient-privileges.613727/)

which I think could have something to do with it, but I cannot give my user any more priveleges though Cpanel.

I hope someone can help me guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your transaction isn't committed (database lingo for saved) properly and I think so because you say you're using an action called 'Find...' which sound like a read-only transaction. Try using an action for inserting/updating data, I don't really know anything about Zapier but it looks like there is some kind of `New Row` action that should work.

Maybe the select part at the end will not work then but I guess then you need to use a trigger